# Busy-Beaver-like question for WHILE-Programs (Theoretical CS)

Tags: computability, halting-problem, busy-beaver

So this is exam-task is called "Busy WHILE-Programs"

In our lecture it was proven that WHILE-Programs are turing-complete. In short a WHILE-Program only allows the following:

```
Variables             x1,x2,...  (initially all 0 and can only be positive)
Constants c           0,1,2,3,...
Assignment            xi := c
Addition/Subtraction  xi := xj + c, xi := xj - c
while-loops           while(xi != 0) { ... }
```

In part (a) of the task we should show, that every WHILE-program can be simulated by a WHILE42-program.

A WHILE42-program is a WHILE-program where all constants can only be 42 or lower.

Now the task where I need help (I try to translate from german):

*Let WHILE42(n) be the subset of all WHILE42-programs, with no more than n instructions/commands. The function g(n) returns the biggest value, a terminating program from the WHILE42(n)-subset assigns any of it's variables. Prove or disprove the following statement:*

`The function g(n) is not computable`

I have two routes with the second being probably a valid answer:

**First:** My intuition tells me it is not computable and that I should show (like in the Busy-Beaver-example) that if it would be computable, it would solve the Halting-problem. Which would show, that it can't be computable.

My thought-process so far:

If `g(n)` is computable, I could take any TM `M_1` and transform it in a WHILE42-program `W_1` with `n_1` commands.
I could then calculate `g(n_1)`.

Then I need to show that from this value `g(n_1)` I can derive somehow an upper value of how many steps I need to simulate `M_1` to decide if it will terminate or run forever.

But I struggle to determine what this upper value is.

**Second:** Here my intuition tells me, that this is not how it is expected to be solved. So I would prefer a solution to the first one, if there is any

If `g(n)` is computable, there is a TM `M_g` that calculates `g(n)`. `M_g` could be transformed in a WHILE42-program `W_g` with `n_g` commands.

Since `W_g` would for any `n` at some point assign the highest value for this WHILE42(n)-subset, `g(n_g)` can not compute a value. For any value k  `g(n_g)` could return, it would be possible to construct a terminating WHILE42-Programm that adds the value `42` k-times to a variable which would grow larger than k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured it out for the **first** solution.

If I would have `g(n_1)` and this would be the limit of any variable of a WHILE42(n_1) can possibly be, this would mean that I could calculate every configuartion `W_1` could possibly have. With a configuration being the value of all variables (from `0` to `g(n_1)`) and the state (the operation which is about to be executed).

No WHILE42-program that terminates can ever be in the exact same configuration. So if any WHILE42-program runs more operations than the number of possible configurations I therefore know, it will not terminate.
=> this would solve the halting problem for WHILE42 and therefore also for TMs.

=> g(n) is not computable

Answer (score 1):

Use the same proof as Radó did in his paper: Assume there is a program $\Sigma$ that computes the value asked for, combine with a program that given $n$ computes $2 n$, and add $1$ to the result. Call the number of lines of the result $N$. Writing a program that computes $N$ should take at most $N$ lines (add $1$ $N$ times). Combine the above, the result is of length $2 N$ and computes a value larger than the largest it is able to compute given it's length. Contradiction, $\Sigma$ can't exist.